# error trying to display a preselected element in v-autocomplete

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a strange behaviour using a v-autocomplete.
I can use it normaly to select an element but when I reload it,
I am trying to set the value selected but it is not displayed.
Here is the code used:

```
 <v-autocomplete
   name="driversform"
   :items="drivers"
   item-text="name"
   item-value="id"
   v-model="transport.driver"
   :rules="driverRules"
   :search-input.sync="searchDriver"
   label="Conducteur"
   prepend-icon="event_seat"
    persistent-hint>

 private async created(): Promise<void> {
    const transportId = +this.$route.params.id;
    if (transportId) {
        this.transport =await this.apiService.getTransport(transportId)
        this.transport.driver = this.transport.driver || new ResourceDto();
        console.log(this.transport.driver);
    }
}
```

this.transport.driver is effectively set but the result is not displayed in my autocomplete...

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my problem by populating the 'drivers' list before getting the selected member